# QtSql Dynamic Select query with multiple WHERE filters

Tags: c++, sql, qt, where-clause, qtsql

- I need to execute any select query using the same method.
- So, the query my has to filter the selected data using one value or
  more.
- Filters are stored in a map that has the **column name** as the **key**  and
  the **filtering value** as its **value**.
- So my Question is : **how to add filters dynamically into Select statement?**
- **What I tried:**

  **1. QSqlQueryModel Class:**
          I could create a **QSqlQueryModel**  object  and set a query to 
          retrieve the whole table data but, I 
          could not find any functionality in this class to filter this data :

  ```
     QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
     model->setQuery("SELECT * FROM employee");
  ```

  **2. QSqlTableModel:** This class is used to view table data in a **qtableView**,I can use this class to read table data and then filter this data like this (I have not tried this yet):

  ```
   QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel
   model->setTable("employee");
   model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
   model->select();
   model->setFilter("colum5 > 10");
   // I can use after that data() method to retrieve filtered data.
  ```

  **3. For Loop** I thought about using for loop to add filters directly but, I would prefer a better way because I believe that QT offers a such service.

---

**The method shall looks like this:**

```
/**
 * @brief getData executes sql select query.
 * @param query [out] QSqlQuery query object after executing the query.
 * @param queryFilters [in] map of query filters (column-name, filter- 
   value).
 * @param table [in] table name.
 * @return 
 */
bool getData(QSqlQuery &query, std::map<std::string,QVariant> &queryFilters, 
std::string &table){
        bool status = false;
        std::string queryText = "SELECT * from " + table + " WHERE  ";
        // I should apply filters from queryFilters map here.
        return status;
}
```

Comment: Why not use [`QMap`](doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html) ?

Comment: It is not about using map or another stl class.I am asking about :  how to add the filters dynamically into the query statement.

Comment: You'll encounter a lot of converting between STL/QTL types. So might as well get started using QString and QMap/QHash. Have you tried using a loop for that matter? :-)

Comment: Yap, I missed this point. thanks!

Comment: Usually with a _variable_ number of variables, loops are the way to go.

Also, just eyeing your string, `"SELECT * from" + table + "WHERE  "` be careful to place spaces before/after `table` unless you can guarantee that there are spaces. "SELECT * frommyTableWHERE..." won't execute.

Comment: I thought about using loop for this matter.But, I thought  that there is a better way using some qt classes like : QSqlQueryModel

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I think that i will use a for loop directly inside query statement as my last solution!! :).

Comment: Hi again. If you thought `QSqlQueryModel` might've been a better solution, please include that in your question as it tells us about your thought process: what worked, what didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this.

### Using a for-loop with `std::map`.

Use a *`for`* loop  to iterate through your key-pair values.

```
bool getData(QSqlQuery &query, const std::map<std::string,QVariant> &queryFilters,
             std::string &table)
{
    // ...

    std::string queryText = "SELECT * from " + table + " WHERE";
    
    for (auto it = queryFilters.begin(); it != queryFilters.end(); )
    {
        queryText += " " + it->first + "='" + it->second.toString().toStdString() + "'";
    
        it++;
        // check the iterator isn't the last iterator
        if (it != queryFilters.end())
            queryText += " AND";    // separate your "filters" using an AND
    }

    // ...      
}
```

---

### Using a for-loop with `QMap`.

But heck this is Qt so why not take advantage of the [`QMap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html), [`QStringList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html), and [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) QTL types.

```
bool getData(QSqlQuery &query, const QMap<QString, QVariant> &queryFilters,
             const QString &table)
{
    //  ...
    
    QString queryText = "SELECT * from " + table + " WHERE ";
    QStringList filters;
    foreach (const QString &filterKey, queryFilters.keys())
        filters << filterKey + "='" + queryFilters.value(filterKey).toString() + "'";
    
    queryText += filters.join(" AND ");
    
    //  ...
    
}
```

Note that `foreach` is a Qt-defined macro. See [*the foreach keyword*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword).

For other QTL types you might want to be aware of, see [*containers*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html).

---

### QSqlQueryModel???

I can't tell from your question and comments whether you actually have an sql table model/view/widget in the background or whether you're using something else entirely.

> I thought about using loop for this matter.But, I thought that there is a better way using some qt classes like : QSqlQueryModel

For sure, just browsing through the documentation, [`QSqlQueryModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html) doesn't have a filter feature.

**But**... [`QSqlTableModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter) *does* have this feature. The plus side is, that if you already have a `QSqlQueryModel` sitting somewhere, you could upgrade it to a `QSqlTableModel` since the latter inherits the former. But again, I don't have enough information to make judgements so I'm just leading you around in the dark here.

Hopefully, this answer sheds some light on your predicament along with the reminder of how you could ask a better question to obtain more accurate responses.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about using QsqlTableModel. But, I think that it has to retrive all table data before i can do any process. And, i will update my question and add more details.

Comment: I think that using foreach loop is the best solution for now. I marked this answer as accepted. Howervere i will update my question whenever i find another approach.

Comment: Glad you found this somewhat useful. `for` loops should be the most straightforward. :-) You seem worried that `for` loops can't handle it though.  Lot's of filters?

Comment: I think that there are not too many Filters!.For now I will use a foreach loop.And I will use also  QTL classes instead of STL  :).